# Making cover pic with fb js sdk

Tags: javascript, facebook

Hey guys i have decided to make an application in facebook.So i have decided to go on with js sdk.

I want to add an image as a cover pic via sdk.So i have came across [sdk doc](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/album).

The code which i have tried.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html>
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
</head>
<body>
<script>
var c = document.getElementById('boom');

function statusChangeCallback(response) {
console.log('statusChangeCallback');
console.log(response);

if (response.status === 'connected') {
  // Logged into your app and Facebook.
  testAPI();
} else if (response.status === 'not_authorized') {

  document.getElementById('status').innerHTML = 'Please log ' +
    'into this app.';
} else {

  document.getElementById('status').innerHTML = 'Please log ' +
    'into Facebook.';
}


}

  function checkLoginState() {
FB.getLoginStatus(function(response) {
  statusChangeCallback(response);
});


}



  window.fbAsyncInit = function() {
  FB.init({
appId      : '289533237896176',
cookie     : true,  

xfbml      : true,  
version    : 'v2.1'
  });





  FB.getLoginStatus(function(response) {
statusChangeCallback(response);
  });
  };





  (function(d, s, id) {
var js, fjs = d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0];
if (d.getElementById(id)) return;
js = d.createElement(s); js.id = id;
js.src = "//connect.facebook.net/en_US/sdk.js";
fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js, fjs);
  }(document, 'script', 'facebook-jssdk'));




  function testAPI() {
var imgURL="http://farm4.staticflickr.com/3332/3451193407_b7f047f4b4_o.jpg";

FB.api('/album_id/photos', 'post', {
message:'photo description',
url:imgURL        
}, function(response){


if (!response || response.error) {
    alert('Error occured');
} else {
    alert('Post ID: ' + response.id);
}


});




}



</script>



<fb:login-button scope="public_profile,email,publish_actions" onlogin="checkLoginState();">
</fb:login-button>



<div id="status">
</div>



</body>
</html>
```

This code works fine actually..But it doesnt allow me to post the image as cover photo.

Can anyone tell me how to do this ..Any help would be appreciated..Thanx

Answer (score 2):

You cannot post the Cover photo via the Graph API.

See

- https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/v2.2/user/#nopublishdeleting

Comment: then pleae have a look on this website ..http://coverjunction.com/cover/it-s-me-1-2-3..It enables to add the an image as cover pic from the api

Comment: Yes, that's because they're making use og the v1.0 Graph API. I guess don't have one, so the v2.2 docs are valid.

Comment: when i used like http://graph.facebook.com/[userid]?fields=cover i get the result inb= a json format including my cover image ..is there something i can do with this request??..I have seen many websites using this type of action with the cover pic ..is this possible to do with v2.2 api ??

Comment: You can't update fields of the `user` object, as the docs say. Afaik this has changed from v1.0 to v2.0, but the old v1.0 docs are no longer online

Comment: so you are saying this cant be done with the current api ??..but the functionality is still available in many of the websites

Comment: Yes, that's what I said in my answer. And yes, there are still sites which use the v1.0 of the Graph API which was potentially capable of doing this. Graph API v1.0 will stop being usable on April 30th 2015, and isn't usable for apps which have been created after April 30th 2014.

Comment: ..in many webistes i have seen that when a user clicks on the image and click on make as cover button a new album is made and the selected image is added to the album.i can do this with the current api.but the other thing i had seen is that it prompts a user to make that pic as a cover pic by saving changes ..i cant do that action with the current api..i mean can this prompt action of cover pic be done with this api ??

Comment: did you get my question ??..i mean is that action possible with the current api ??

Comment: You can upload an image, no question. But you can't set it as cover photo via the v2.2 Graph API. End of story.

Comment: i know what you are saying about..i am asking wheather i can ask for a prompt ..like appearing the cover photo in the timeline and asking for saving changes ..is this possible with the current api ??