# how to change facebook user cover page using facebook graph api

Tags: php, facebook

i try this way . please help me

$this->load->library('src/facebook.php'); 
$fb = new Facebook(array('appId' => APP_ID, 'secret' => SECRET_ID));

```
    $photo_uploaded = $fb->api('/USER FACEBOOK ID/feed', "POST", array(
        'access_token' => "HERE USER ACCESS TOKEN",
        'picture' => 'IMAGE URL', // remote URL to image
        'name' => "Testing",
        'description' => "This is testing msg"
    ));
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to update the profile cover photo using Graph API?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17493384/how-to-update-the-profile-cover-photo-using-graph-api)

Comment: possible duplicate of [Making cover pic with fb js sdk](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27272216/making-cover-pic-with-fb-js-sdk)

Answer (score 1):

It's not possible to change the cover photo for a User via the Graph API, as explained in [Making cover pic with fb js sdk](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27272216/making-cover-pic-with-fb-js-sdk/27274026#27274026)